# Customize Return Key text in JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'd like to make the keyboard Return key say "Send" when the user is typing in a JSQMessageViewController. I know I can do this in a normal Text Field as follows: `myTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.send`

But how do I get access to JSQMessagesViewController's text field so I can change the return key type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to just  `inputToolbar.contentView!.textView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.send`

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked. I only knew the answer because I had to go dig for it one day.